# Include NULL values in MySQL SELECT results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MySQL tables:

tbl_pet_owners:

```
+----+--------+----------+--------+--------------+
| id | name   | pet      | city   | date_adopted |
+----+--------+----------+--------+--------------+
|  1 | jane   | cat      | Boston | 2017-07-11   |
|  2 | jane   | dog      | Boston | 2017-07-11   |
|  3 | jane   | cat      | Boston | 2017-06-11   |
|  4 | jack   | cat      | Boston | 2016-07-11   |
|  5 | jim    | snake    | Boston | 2017-07-11   |
|  6 | jim    | goldfish | Boston | 2017-07-11   |
|  7 | joseph | cat      | NYC    | 2016-07-11   |
|  8 | sam    | cat      | NYC    | 2017-07-11   |
|  9 | drew   | dog      | NYC    | 2016-07-11   |
| 10 | jack   | frog     | Boston | 2017-07-19   |
+----+--------+----------+--------+--------------+
```

tbl_pet_types:

```
+----------+-------------+
| pet      | type        |
+----------+-------------+
| cat      | mammal      |
| dog      | mammal      |
| goldfish | fish        |
| goldfish | seacreature |
| snake    | reptile     |
+----------+-------------+
```

I have the following SELECT statement

```
SELECT DISTINCT owners.name, owners.pet, owners.city,
group_concat(DISTINCT types.type separator ', ') AS type
FROM tbl_pet_owners owners
INNER JOIN tbl_pet_types types ON owners.pet = types.pet
WHERE owners.city = 'Boston' OR owners.city = 'NYC'
GROUP BY owners.name, owners.pet
ORDER BY owners.city
```

..which returns this result:

```
+--------+----------+--------+-------------------+
| name   | pet      | city   | type              |
+--------+----------+--------+-------------------+
| jack   | cat      | Boston | mammal            |
| jane   | cat      | Boston | mammal            |
| jane   | dog      | Boston | mammal            |
| jim    | goldfish | Boston | fish, seacreature |
| jim    | snake    | Boston | reptile           |
| drew   | dog      | NYC    | mammal            |
| joseph | cat      | NYC    | mammal            |
| sam    | cat      | NYC    | mammal            |
+--------+----------+--------+-------------------+
```

Unfortunately, jack's frog is omitted from the results because there is no entry for frog in tbl_pet_types. How can I edit my query to include jack's frog in the results (with type = NULL)?

Comment: Change your `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and let 'er rip. `INNER JOIN` says "Only return results where the join condition is true". `LEFT OUTER JOIN` says "Return all results from the first table and only those results from the left-join'd table where the condition is true"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join)

Comment: @JNevill I think those conditions in the `WHERE` clause also need to be moved to the `ON` clause.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The WHERE clause conditions are all on the Left-Most/First table, so I believe they should stay. Putting them in the `ON` clause would be an odd move in this case.

Comment: @JNevill You're correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a LEFT JOIN to the tbl_pet_types instead of an INNER JOIN. What an INNER JOIN does is make sure you only see the records on both tables that are matching. In this particular case, you want all of the tbl_pet_owners data regardless if it's matching tbl_pet.

```
SELECT DISTINCT owners.name, owners.pet, owners.city,
group_concat(DISTINCT types.type separator ', ') AS type
FROM tbl_pet_owners owners
LEFT JOIN tbl_pet_types types ON owners.pet = types.pet
WHERE owners.city = 'Boston' OR owners.city = 'NYC'
GROUP BY owners.name, owners.pet
ORDER BY owners.city
```

Comment: No need to use `DISTINCT` in the select clause, and `owners.city` should possibly be included in the `GROUP BY` list.

Answer (score 2):

You're using an `INNER JOIN` so since there isn't a match on both tables, that row won't show up. Try using a `LEFT JOIN` so that all values in the left (first) table will show up, regardless of if there is an answer on the right (second) table.

You can visualize this with this image
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest the following query, which is similar to what you had originally but with a few modifications.

```
SELECT
    owners.name,
    owners.pet,
    owners.city,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT COALESCE(types.type, 'NA') separator ', ') AS type
FROM tbl_pet_owners owners
LEFT JOIN tbl_pet_types types
    ON owners.pet = types.pet
WHERE owners.city = 'Boston' OR owners.city = 'NYC'
GROUP BY owners.name, owners.pet, owners.city
ORDER BY owners.city
```

You don't need to use `DISTINCT` in your select clause, because `GROUP BY` will already achieve what you had in mind.  The most major change was switching to a `LEFT JOIN`.  This should prevent records from being dropped.